# SK Scene transition background

Tags: ios7, xcode5, sprite-kit

I've just started to learn how to program with xCode and more specifically with the new SpriteKit. So bare in mind I'm kind of new to this.

I've managed to move to a different scene by pressing on a label, but somehow the background of my scene has gone all wrong. the background should be like the first scene, but it gave me a background with two horizontal bars. I don't think I've done anything wrong since I've just copied the code needed to set the background to the second scene.

1st scene:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/kyud.png/

2nd scene:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/198/472h.png/

my code used to set up both backgrounds:

```
SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"background_start"];
    background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    background.xScale = 0.7;
    background.yScale = 0.7;
    [self addChild:background];
```

transition is done with:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
/* Called when a touch begins */

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

if([node.name isEqualToString:@"startgame"]){
    Options_Scene *gs = [[Options_Scene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    SKTransition *doors = [SKTransition doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration:0.5];
    [self.view presentScene:gs transition:doors];
}
```

}

PS: I find it odd why I have to scale it to 0.7 when the background actually has the dimensions 480x320.

Comment: 1) check scaleMode of the scene and 2) check initial scene's size (should be 480x320). The latter is a known issue, even if the app only supports landscape iOS initially launches the app in portrait mode and reports the size as portrait until a certain point (viewWillAppear I think). Check if you get 480x320 or 320x480 for the initial scene.

Comment: scalemode in both scenes are menu.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

Answer (score 0):

As you are using landscape I would swap the

```
viewWillAppear
```

With

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;

if (!skView.scene) {
    //skView.showsFPS = YES;
    //skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [PMyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
}
```